# docker-compose external_link mongo network not reachable

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I am having a strange situation where I can not connect to my running mongo DB in my docker compose. My compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: myimage:latest
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    external_links:
     - myname:mongo
    environment:
     - MONGO_URL=mongodb://myname:27017/test
```

I have found a few infos on that that all did not solve my issue. I.e. I tried:

1)

Create a custom network:

```
docker network create mongonet
```

Then start mongo with the `--network mongonet` flag and add to the compose:

```
networks:
  default: 
    external:
      name: mongonet
```

Got nothing there either.

I looked into my /etc/hosts file on my compose, and it did not list any DNS entry.

If i do a `docker inspect` and grab the mongo IP and add it to my compose, that is fine and works like a charm.

I start mongo like this:

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v ~/mongo_data:/data/db  mongo
```

I am really rather confused as I believed this to be a out-of-the-box kind of thing. Strangely I can't make it work. I have found examples on internal links (vs external_link) but that does not work for me as I have many services that I would like to run like this and not all of them should run at the same time.

I start my docker compose as this:

`docker-compose up --force-recreate`

My versions are:

`docker-compose version 1.17.1, build 6d101fb`

`Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be`

My question: How do I successfully link a running mongo container as an external link into my application containers such that they can connect to them?

My docker PS:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
5cf6e08d6fde        mongo               "docker-entrypoint..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   gallant_feynman
```

Comment: It is "mongo" the actual name for the container or just the image? can you post a docker ps? you are not setting a name in docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v ~/mongo_data:/data/db  mongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links are deprecated, use networks instead.

> Notes:
>
> If you’re using the version 2 or above file format, the
>   externally-created containers must be connected to at least one of the
>   same networks as the service which is linking to them. Links are a
>   legacy option. We recommend using networks instead.

The network way should work. I think you are missing some pieces. Make sure to give the mongo container a name, and make sure to attach the app container to the network in the compose file:

```
docker network create mongonet
```

---

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --network mongonet --name mongo -v ~/mongo_data:/data/db mongo
```

---

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: myimage:latest
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    environment:
     - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/test
    networks:
      - mongonet

networks:
  default: 
    external:
      name: mongonet
```

Comment: You are my hero! You were absolutely right, I forgot to set the name. In the docker ps i confused the "image" with the "name" part and ran around in circles for 3 hours until you pointed it out. It was so easy .. all works now! Thank you!